# How to setup noVNC using TightVNC on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, tightvnc

I have installed TightVNC on an Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2008.

I am able to use VNC using TightVNC viewer properly. Now I want to setup noVNC on it. How can I do that?

Comment: You should show some research effort. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK according to readme of websockify project from [this github page](https://github.com/novnc/websockify) you should download websockify zip-archive, unzip it and run executable wrapper named "run" from the unzipped directory like this:
    ./run 5901 --wrap-mode=ignore -- vncserver -geometry 1024x768 :1
And after this on the client machine you should use noVNC client from noVNC project on [the same github page](https://github.com/novnc/websockify).

Answer (score 0):

The npm version of websockify works great on Windows. Follow these steps:

1. Install NodeJS (the default global installation path is: %AppData%\npm, %AppData%\npm-cache)
2. Install required components, run:

   npm install -g express
   npm install -g optimist
   npm install -g policyfile
   npm install -g ws
   npm install -g http-server
   npm install -g mime-types
   npm install -g pkg
3. Create a folder named "websockify" under "%AppData%\npm\node_modules" and copy the contents of folder "websockify\other\js" in it.
4. Run (documentation of arguments -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg): pkg "%AppData%\npm\node_modules\websockify\websockify.js" --targets "latest-win-x86,latest-win-x64" --out-path "your output folder"

Credit to gdan101: https://github.com/novnc/websockify/issues/67#issuecomment-354792644